# How to quickly used format to print a list?

Tags: python, numpy, format

I have a numpy array and I would like to print the values of this array with a specific format.

I can do the follwing, with `x` the numpy array of length 3 :

```
print((3*"%12.6f") % tuple(x))
```

Is there a way to do the same things with the `format` method of string objects ? Until now, the only working solution I have is the following and is less easy :

```
print("{:12.6f} {:12.6f} {:12.6f}".format(x[0], x[1], x[2]))
```

Moreover, I guess that `format` is the python3 syntax and I would like to switch to this syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same string multiplication trick you originally used. You just have to use argument unpacking on `x`.

```
print(("{:12.6f} "*3).format(*x))
```

...Although I'd be more inclined to use a generator expression here.

```
print("".join("{:12.6f}".format(item) for item in x))
```

Comment: You may simply change hardcoded `3` to `*len(x)` to get nice, generic solution.

Comment: What does `*x` mean ?

Comment: @Ger, [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).